# How to set network proxy to ignore “localhost” on Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, localhost

I would like to ignore `localhost` on Windows 10. In Ubuntu, you go to “Network Proxy > Manual > Ignore Hosts” then type `localhost`.

How can I do the same thing in Windows 10? I tried the following, but when I do so, I can’t access the internet.

[image: My proxy settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a proxy server, which requires *localhost* in order to function, then that will result in no internet access... You also may want to ignore *localhost* in its entirety, which in turn, you can (but not without losing internet access...)

Albeit there is a bypass:

**Firstly**: Navigate to notepad, (Search for Notepad (press the Start button and type its name) and right-click the app to display the context menu) and open the app with ***with administrator privileges***  (To be able to disable *localhost* successfully, you must open *Notepad* with **administrator privileges**, so the effect can take place in Windows.)

**Then**: With Notepad open in administrator mode, you’re ready to open the file. Click File > Open and browse to the file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (you can copy and paste this into the address bar at the top of the Open window).

**Lastly**: Now you’re ready to make the necessary changes to edit the file. ((If you’ve never opened the hosts file before, all you’ll see is a short section of text describing its purpose and how to make edits.

The hosts file is a simple mapping of IP addresses and hostnames. Each entry goes on a newline, with the IP address (that’s the numerical address) first, followed by a space or tab character and then the hostname (or domain). You can add comments to the file by placing a “#” character at the start of the line – this will make Windows ignore the line when reading the file.

(At this point, you may be wondering why you’d ever need to edit the hosts file.) While it is more useful to technical users, there are also a few more general cases in which it might have value. One example is if you wanted to block a certain website, for example, Google. By adding an entry for 'google.com' to the hosts file, you can force Windows to point the address to a different location – so users won’t be able to visit the site.

To achieve this example, add a line such as '0.0.0.0 www.google.com' to the file. Save the file and try and visit Google in your browser. You should find the site fails to load....))

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little confused.. what's the point of opening notepad? Since I will open the file in the browse? And the other thing, "**lastly**" - do you mean to go to the file location and making the necessary changes there? What would I need to do to disable `localhost`? Delete its lines from the file or what?

Comment: Sorry, that was a spelling mistake, I mean browser not browse.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question in the post but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.